# Is this the most efficient JavaScript for comparing two arrays of objects and modifying properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I've got a method below that is in an Ecma 6 component (Salesforce Lightning Web Components if any one is curious). I have added it here because this is more JavaScript than LWC question. Is this the best way to accomplish the task.

I have two arrays, both are of objects:
I want to compare the arrays, and create a new array of objects that has a new property `required: true` or `required: false`. Is this the most efficient way to do this?

```js
const RequiredFields = 
  [ { fieldApiName: 'FirstName', value: 'Test'         } 
  , { fieldApiName: 'LastName',   value: 'LastNameTest' } 
  ]

const AllFields = 
  [ { fieldApiName: 'FirstName', value: 'Test'         } 
  , { fieldApiName: 'LastName',   value: 'LastNameTest' } 
  , { fieldApiName: 'Suffix',     value: ''             } 
  ] 

addRequiredFields(RequiredFields, Allfields) {
  RequiredFields.forEach(field => {
    field.required = true; 
  });

  Allfields.forEach(field => {
    var hasVal = Object.values(field).includes(true); 
    if (hasVal) {
      console.log(field.fieldApiName + ' = TRUE'); 
    } else {
      field.required = false; 
    }
    console.log(field); 
    
  });
  return Allfields;  
}

console.log ( addRequiredFields(RequiredFields, Allfields) )
```

```
output =  [ 
    { fieldApiName: FirstName, value: 'Test' , required: true} 
  , { fieldApiName: LastName,   value: 'LastNameTest' , required: true} 
  , { fieldApiName: Suffix,     value: '', required: false            } 
  ]
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: How do you (want to) measure efficiency?

Comment: Updating the fields expected to return.

Comment: efficiency would be lines of code.

Comment: Also, would like an explanation for why this is -1.  If it needs to be modified or doesn't fit this forum, I'm happy to edit it and adjust what's necessary.

Comment: yes the code works. it's just a typo. Should be `fieldApiName`

Comment: @MisterJojo there is a server request that occurs from Salesforce on this one. The structure here is what occurs after array is constructed by the server.

Comment: @MisterJojo I just double checked my syntax from output in the console. It is correct, JS runner is getting buggy. can add a screenshot.

Comment: `"SyntaxError: unexpected token: '{'" `,   on `addRequiredFields` aren't you forget to writing `function` somewhere ?

Comment: Lines of code makes for a bad metric, but it's the one you chose, so: line breaks are optional in JS, so you can collapse everything onto a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some feedback:

- The line in your code `var hasVal = Object.values(field).includes(true);` could cause bugs because it'll return true if *any* key is assigned value `true`. We only want to check value assigned to key `required`.
- Instead of mutating the array `AllFields`, try `.map()` to return a new array. Immutable programming has simplicity to it that usually makes it easier to follow.

Here's a simpler solution using `.map()` and `.some()`

```js
const RequiredFields = [
  { fieldApiName: 'FirstName', value: 'Test'},
  { fieldApiName: 'LastName', value: 'LastNameTest' }
];

const AllFields = [
  { fieldApiName: 'FirstName', value: 'Test'},
  { fieldApiName: 'LastName', value: 'LastNameTest' },
  { fieldApiName: 'Suffix', value: ''}
];

const result = AllFields.map(field => ({
  ...field,
  required: RequiredFields.some(
    ({fieldApiName}) => fieldApiName === field.fieldApiName
  )
}));

console.log('result', result);
```

Comment: Thanks, researching the syntax a bit more but that's what I was looking for. Little fuzzy on whats going on with the elipse notation `...field,` and `({fieldApiName}) => fieldApiName === field.fieldApiName)` if you can offer more details. that would be helpful. Thank!

Comment: The `...` is the [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) that includes all properties from an object. The `{fieldApiName}` is the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) which unpacks the property `fieldApiName` from the field. The `fieldApiName === field.fieldApiName` is a condition which checks if the two values are equal to each other.

Answer (score 1):

do that, use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
const
  RequiredFields = 
    [ { fieldApiName: 'FirstName', value: 'Test'         } 
    , { fieldApiName: 'LastName',  value: 'LastNameTest' } 
    ]
, Allfields = 
  [ { fieldApiName: 'FirstName', value: 'Test'         } 
  , { fieldApiName: 'LastName',  value: 'LastNameTest' } 
  , { fieldApiName: 'Suffix',    value: ''             } 
  ];

function addRequiredFields( ReqF , data)
  {
  data.forEach( row =>
    row.required = ReqF.some( x =>
      x.fieldApiName === row.fieldApiName 
    ) )
  }

addRequiredFields( RequiredFields, Allfields )

console.log ( Allfields )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```